# How to Display ActivityIndicator and call api Everytime in LazyLoading Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

Below is my Code..

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)

   {

      if scrollView == MainAllProductCollectionView

  {

      if ((scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height) >= 
        scrollView.contentSize.height)

   {

                    if !isNewDataLoading
                    {
                        if case helperInstance.isConnectedToNetwork()
                        {

                            isNewDataLoading = true

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Please help me on this problem.

Comment: Please add some details to your question, and [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do you have an actual question?  It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following line to show the activity indicator.

```
UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
```

You can use the following line to hide the activity indicator.

```
UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
```